# Using js to determine if an element's width is determined by its content?

Tags: jquery, css, width

I want to know if there's a way I can use jQuery or javascript to determine, given an element, if its width is set by a css style (either inline, inherited or directly) or if its being determined by the size/length of its content.

Comment: You could examine the element using Firebug

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do so using jQuery or you just want to test to see if it is period? If it's the ladder use Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug

Comment: sorry, using jQuery.. I know about firebug etc already. I'll edit to clarify

Comment: I'm having a hard time setting up a useful test case. Could you give us some sample code?

Comment: @Scott http://jsfiddle.net/pt6XN/7/

Comment: @Pekka Oh, I was being obtuse and misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Is the children stuff inside the element to determine the width dynamic? If you know what the element would be, you just have to determine each element's with and compare it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea comes to mind:

- Store the element's `.width()`
- Remove all children of the element, move them elsewhere, or make them `display: none`
- Check out the element's `.width()`. If it has changed, it depended on the content. If it has not changed, it was set using CSS.
- Restore the children's `display` property or move them back if necessary.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pt6XN/13/) is a *very* primitive prototype that simply removes all the element's content:

```
function determineWidth(jQueryElement)
{
   var widthBefore = jQueryElement.width();

  jQueryElement.html(""); // Empty the element

  var widthAfter = jQueryElement.width();

  if (widthAfter != widthBefore)
    var result = "The width depended on the content.";
   else
    var result = "The width did NOT depend on the content.";

  alert("Before: "+widthBefore+" After: "+widthAfter+" - "+result);

}
```

There's one side-effect for block level elements: Since their width doesn't depend on the content, the script will return "...did not depend...." even though the element may not have had an explicit width set in CSS as you require.